# Interactive Brokers IB_INSYNC API - why I can only send one order at a time

Tags: python, tkinter, interactive-brokers

I am developing a trading application based on Interactive Brokers in_insync API.

Below is my code and I am wondering why I can only send one order at a time. Once I have called the **placetrade()** function the order is transmitted to IB but if I want to send another order I can only do that after restarting the application.
I cannot find any info in the ib_insync docs where it says only 1 order is allowed. I suspect it could be something to do with the OrderID, but then again I am not really sure.

Any ideas how what I need to do to allow multiple orders ?

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text 
import os
from ib_insync import *
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
#

import ibapi
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi import contract 
from ibapi.order import *
import threading
import time


root = tk.Tk()

#Port 7496 for TWS Live account and 7497 for paper trading and 4002 for Gateway
ib = IB() 
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1) 

        
def definecontract():
    ticker = tickerentry1.get() 
    exchange = "SMART"
    currency = "USD"
    return ticker, exchange, currency


def defineorder():
    direction = tradeentry1.get()
    ordersize = qtyentry1.get()       
    orderprice = priceentry1.get()
    return direction, ordersize, orderprice


def placetrade():
    ticker, exchange, currency = definecontract()
    direction, ordersize, orderprice = defineorder()
    
    contract = Stock(ticker, exchange, currency)
    order = LimitOrder(direction, ordersize, orderprice)

    ib.placeOrder(contract, order)

#definition of buttons
placetrade1 = tk.Button(root, text='Trade', padx=10, pady=5, fg='white', bg='grey', command=placetrade)
placetrade1.grid(row=1, column=4)
```

Comment: Why do you think you can only send one order before having to restart? What happens when you send the second order?

Comment: Nothing really happens :-) It just doesn't get transmitted. I thought it could be due to some delays but even after a couple of min, there is no order transmitted whereas the first order gets sent instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the order ID, when using API you need to have unique IDs.  Try global orderId to get the next available id from IBKR

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32555665)